# String + String vs String + String returned from method

Tags: java, string, append, equals

Today while working with String's i have encountered a behavior i don't know before. I'm not able to understand what's happening internally.

```
    public String returnVal(){
         return "5";
     }
 String s1 = "abcd5";
 String s2 = "abcd"+"5";

 String s3 = "abcd5";
 String s4 = "abcd"+returnVal();

 System.out.println(s1 == s2);
 System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
 System.out.println(s3 == s4);
 System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
```

My expectation is printing "true" from all s.o.p's but s3 == s4 is false, why?

Comment: These duplicates don't answer OP's question.

Comment: Mobile app edited instead of adding comment... I previously said that `"abcd"+"5"` is a compile time constant, and is identical to `"abcd5"`, so that is the value used from the string constant pool; whereas `"abcd"+returnVal()` is not compile-time constant, so a new string is created at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner So the "abcd"+returnVal() object is created in the heap  instead of using from scp just like when new operator is used.

Comment: @khelwood, Jens -  the duplicates are not answering my question. it is not a question about  == vs equals() .

Comment: Does this duplicate answer the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java. There are many more. :-) I don’t see how it’s not a question of == versus .equals(). Once you’ve understood that part, I believe you can set your expectations right for OP’s code.

Comment: Once I was teacbhing, emphasizing the use of .equals() between Strings, I told my students that Java’s behaviour of _sometimes_ evaluating == to true was destructive for any teaching effort. :-) Then I showed them an example that looked pretty much the same as the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stumbled across the intricacies of how the Java compiler optimizes `String`.

Suppose I have this program:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "abc";
```

Here the compiler can initialize `a` and `b` to the same `String` instance. This entails that `a == b` and `a.equals(b)`.

Here we also get the same behaviour:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "ab" + "c";
```

This is because `"ab" + "c"` can be evaluated at compile-time to just `"abc"`, which in turn can share an instance with `a`.

This technique is not possible with expressions that call functions:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "ab" + functionThatReturnsC();
```

This is because `functionThatReturnsC` could have side-effects which cannot be resolved at compile-time.

Your case of `returnVal` is interesting. Since it is constant, it could be inlined, in which case the compile-time instance sharing could be applied. It seems the compiler implementer decided not to support this.

This issue exposes a weakness of Java. Since we cannot override `=`, programmers cannot implement custom value-types. Therefore, you should always use `equals` or `Objects.equals` to ensure consistent behaviour.

Note that these optimizations may differ between compilers.

Answer (score 1):

> My expectation is printing "true" from all s.o.p's but s3 == s4 is false, why?

The compiler can do constant expression inlining.  This means that

```
String s1 = "abcd5";
String s2 = "abcd"+"5";
final String five = "5"; // final reference
String sa = "abcd" + five;
```

are all the same (except `five`) and the compiler can simplify all these expressions to `"abcd5"`

However, if the compiler cannot optimise the expression, the operation is performed at runtime and a new String is created. This new String is not a constant which is places in the String literal pool (as it is not a literal in byte code)

```
 String s4 = "abcd" + returnVal(); //  not inlined by the compiler.
 String f5 = "5";  // not a final reference.
 String sb = "abcd" + f5; // evaluated at runtime
```

These create new strings every time they are run (as well as new `StringBuilder` and `char[]`s)